# Why can we produce a composition of two functions, if we know that the codomain of the inner function is equal to the domain of the outer function?

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm having some trouble understanding this. For example if we have functions $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ it seems to me that the only possible way for $g \circ f$ to be defined is if $f(X)$=Y so the range of f must equal it's codomain. For example if we construct $g(f(x))$ then that $f(x)$ is always some element in the range of f, but not necessarily in it's codomain, for example if $f$ isn't surjective. So lets say $f(x)$ is some $y\in Y$(not random) then we have $g(y)$, and since $g$ maps from $Y$ to $Z$ then by definition of a function all elements of Y must be mapped to it's codomain. But lets assume that f isn't surjective so then $g(y)$ can't map all of the elements in it's domain, and the function $g \circ f$ can't be defined. So then when we have this information of where these sets f and g map to and we try to make a composition of f and g, we always have to implicitly assume that f(X)=Y.

Comment: All that's necessary is that the image of $f$ is included in the domain of $g$.

Comment: "$f(x)$ is always some element in the range of $f$, but not necessarily in its co-domain". Can you explain what you mean by this? The range of any function is always a subset of its co-domain, you might have the concepts switched around?

Comment: I think you're getting confused around codomain/range issues (and I'm not precisely sure how). Take a concrete example: let $X=Y=Z=\mathbb{R}$, let $f(x)=x^2$, and let $g(x)=x+3$. There should be no problem thinking about the composition $g\circ f$, it's just $$x\mapsto x^2+3.$$ But $ran(f)$ is very much a proper subset of $Y$.

Comment: @Carlyle yeah you're right. I meant to say basically that if f isn't surjective then g(f(x)) won't be able to map all elements from it's domain Y to Z which is necessary by the definition of a function.

Comment: The domain of the composite $g\circ f$ is not $Y$, but $X$, and every element of $X$ does end up somewhere, so this requirement is still satisfied

Comment: @NoahSchweber I know that I have something wrong, that's why I asked this question for someone to explain it to me. What I'm having trouble with understanding with is that we know that the range of $x^{2}$ is $[0;\infty ]$ so if we have g(f(x)) then that f(x) will always be a real number from  $[0;\infty ]$, but if $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, then that means that g must map all real numbers to it's codomain or else it isn't a function, but here we see that g only maps elements from $[0;\infty ]$ if we try to construct g(f(x)), this is what bugs me.

Comment: @hellusENG I think you're assuming that, in the composition $g\circ f$, "all the data" of $g$ needs to be used. That's not true: it's totally fine if some, or even most, of $g$ is not "called upon" in the composition. The only danger is if $f$ outputs something not in the domain of $g$; think of the distinction between not being asked to do all the things you know how to do, and being asked to do something you don't know how to do ("you" being $g$, here).

Comment: In particular, it's perfectly fine to have $g\circ f$ and $h\circ f$ be the same function even when $g$ and $h$ are different functions. (Take e.g. $f$ and $g$ as in my first comment, and let $h(x)=\vert x\vert +3$.)

Comment: @Carlyle I understand, but if we calculate f(x) first then we get f(x) equals some $y\in Y$ and so we get g(y), and since f isn't surjective we know that g won't me able to map all of the elements in it's domain in this case. since $f(X) \subsetneq Y$

Comment: I am not sure I understand your concern. $g$ is defined before we take the composite, it is assumed to be a well defined function, it has the property that "everything in the domain gets mapped somewhere". When we compose it with $f$, nothing about $g$ changes, it is still the same function, and it still has the property of being "able to map everything in its domain somewhere"

Comment: @NoahSchweber Alright, so if I understand this correctly as Carlyle already commented that we already assume that g is already well defined and so there is no contradiction if in the composition g doesn't map all the elements of it's domain? so if we have for example $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where the range of f is lets say {1,2,3}, it's still possible to make a composition of f and g?

Comment: @hellusENG Yes, that's correct. It might help to think of $g$ as a resource; you never have to use *all* of your resource, you just have to not *exceed* it.

Comment: @hellusENG It may also help to note that you **can** make sense of "the part of $g$ used in $g\circ f$" - this is the *restriction* of $g$ to have domain $im(f)$ (call this "$g_{im(f)}$"). This satisfies, for example, the fact that whenever $g,h$ are functions whose domains include $im(f)$ and which satisfy $g_{im(f)}=h_{im(f)}$ we have $g\circ f=h\circ f$. So there are meaningful things we can say about "how much" of $g$ is actually called upon in a given composition.

Comment: (Incidentally, I'm holding off on making an answer since I think @Carlyle has more successfully addressed your issue.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber my answer is a simple analogy, I am not in the mood to do an in depth technical analysis, by all means if you are, do go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your reply to @NoahSchweber's comment, I think the following analogy will help you:

Think of functions like extension cords. Each cord has a power board with sockets on the one end, and a plug on the other end. An extension cord is useful (a function is well defined respectively) if every socket is connected to the plug on the other end. Now the composite of two cords is obtained by plugging the plug end of one cord into the socket of another, call the receiving cord the one that still has a free plug at the end. Now I presume you would agree that if the receiving cord was useful, and the cord we plugged into it was useful, then the composite will be useful as well, even if the receiving cord didn't have all its sockets occupied.

*This analogy is crude, and not meant to be an analogy for functions in general, or even composition, but only for the interplay between well-definedness and composition